# Authenticate DRF automatically when request comes from page with user logged in. Request Token auth if api request is made externally

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have overwritten the custom user model such that I can login using email instead of username and such that I can redirect to changepassword on first login.

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            if user.last_login is None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('accounts:change_password')
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

I have set up a basic rest API endpoint using DRF

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

When I access the homepage, I need to be logged in:

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

What I would like to do is to authenticate using django.contrib.auth and be redirected to homepage.

When the homepage loads, I would like to perform an AJAX call to display all users.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: '/accounts/users/',
        success: function(result){
                 console.log(result);
                }
    });
```

This call should only work if I am logged in with my user already.

If I access the endpoint externally, let's say in Postman, It should ask me to authenticate.

I should be able to authenticate externally in postman using token authentication.

---

**The question:**

How can I mix the django.contrib.auth authentication with the Django rest_framework Token Authentication in the manner described above? I would like to have a web application and a REST API at the same time. Authenticate in the web application using the django.contrib.auth. Authenticate to REST API using Token. But if user is already logged in the web application perform Rest API request without needing to authenticate again. Can I somehow reuse the web application session?

---

Already customized my user model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Have looked at this, not started implementing yet. I am not sure how they can connect.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

---

---

**Solution**

I accepted the answer below although I found the solution meanwhile. I assumed that you can only add one method of authentication but you can have more. What I actually ended up doing was:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
)
```

It works like a charm. The IsAuthenticated permission is applied globally in my case. In the accepted answer is applied per endpoint

Comment: I did add say in the answer that it can be specified either globally or per view and even added a link to the docs on how to do it globally. But it's good it was of help to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use as many authentication methods as you want. DRF has [SessionAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) that works like the native Django authentication, in addition to its TokenAuthentication. All you need to do is set both authentication  classes either [globally](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) in settings file or per view.

For example, you can set the authentication classes for your `UserViewSet` in this way.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
```

In this way, your web client can use sessions to authenticate, while other clients use tokens.